# Pushing ViewController didn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I try to navigate from one viewcontroller to another in order to pass an object , I use for that

```
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:VC2 animated : YES];
```

but didn't work .
please what I have to do

Comment: Check your TableView Delegates( if you push on selecting a table) are Working or not first mine friend..Check it n reply

Comment: Do you actually have a navigation controller in your app? Try this to test... `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);`

Comment: I didn't use a tableview .I have a button that allows me to navigate from the actual viewcontroller to viewcontroller2.My problem I think is I should add navcontrooller to the viewcontroller , but didn't know how to do that

Comment: yes that's it , how to add navigationcontroller to my viewcontroller .not in the delegate.m , but in viewcontroller.m

Comment: Can you paste the code from your `applicationDidFinishLaunching...` method in the app delegate.

Comment: I got it friend here is the link from which you can learn how to use NAVIGATION in IOS:

[link](http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I didn't have the app here.. , but it contains a navcontroller.please how to add the navcontroller for my viewcontrooler , that I want to push

Comment: that is correct if the view that you want to push is the first view after launshing your app , now if I want to navigate from each viewcontroller to another , how to do that

Comment: Without any code it's pretty much impossible to help.

Comment: is there any way how we could add the navcontroller to any viewcontroller , that what I want to know

Comment: Dude, this is a really common question. Just search Google or Stack Overflow to similar questions.

Comment: for this you can Study this Code sample :  [Sample Code from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ListAdder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010275)

accept Answer if you got :)

Comment: Can you please check if VC2 allocated and initiated.

Comment: You need to create a `UINavigationController` with a root view controller and present it (or make it the window's root view). You don't get one automatically.

Answer (score 2):

try this

In App Delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.ViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and in View Controller.m

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender{
   UIViewController vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UCPAccuracyTableView" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
   [vc2 release]; //if u r nt using ARC
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iF you want to push a viewcontroller, which is not a navigation controller use the following code

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
yourviewcontroller *cdvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardIdentifierName Of the viewcontroller you have to push"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cdvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Delegate.m You need to initialize Navigation controller.

```
RootViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Your nib name" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

After that you can navigate from one controller to another. by

```
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:VC2 animated : YES];
```

Comment: I add this into applicationDidFinishLaunching?? ,but this cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

Make object of Navigation controller then push

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[navController pushviewcontroller:VC2 animated : YES];
```